# Loading Javascript files with custom headers values

Tags: javascript, http

I'm a beginner with Javascript and recently came across this problem. I have to load a Javascript file in script tag but it's protected with `Basic Authentication`.

To access this file I would have to pass `Athorization` HTTP header with appropriate values.

Since this script file is not on the same origin I can't use Ajax to load it.
So I'm pretty much left with the `<script>` tag.

My question is can we pass HTTP headers when loading Javascript files using `<script>` and is it possible to send a POST request or any other request using `<script>` tag ?

Comment: Might I ask why you would want to do this? It can be a serious security issue for your app. If the script is made for embedding in other apps they should provide the appropriate CORS, JSON-P or similar.

Comment: It's an enterprise App and the script is a licensed, they provide script access key for each registered application. On the basis of provided API key providers track the number of requests made by an application, that is different for different licenses.

Comment: You have to use `ajax` for this. Such requests are indeed subject to the same origin policy, but that does not mean that it is not possible. You "only" have to take care to use the correct headers, so you have to "whitelist" that origin for your page. Then the browser will certainly load that script in a dynamic manner.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but origin headers are not in my hands. Server is maintained by the license provide which is another team in the enterprise. I would try asking them if they support changing headers however that's a lot of red tape.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment right now but here is an example of how you can load google maps js script by using ajax.

```
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.0&sensor=false';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "script"
}).success(function (result){
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
         zoom: 8
    });
}).error(function ( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    alert(data.error);
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

Comment: Ajax is not an option because of the CORS policy and script provider is not  providing any Access Controll Allow headers also.

Comment: However I guess second part of my question is answered, as if CORS was not a problem then Ajax call could be used to load script with POST request.

Comment: Do they provide api interface instructions for loading this script? As far as i know CORS methods can be allowed on server side. Sometimes there is callback function in request keys parameters like  Google has "    <script src="https: // maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY& **callback=initMap** "
        async defer></script>"

Comment: imo you just need to remove Ajax request header, it's xmlHttpRequest as I recall, but not sure

Comment: ya this doesnt answer the question